# Inline CSS works, but why not External CSS?

Tags: html, css

Here's my code of index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CodeWare</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com"> <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="hero">
        <h1>Coding</h1
        <h1>Redefined.</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Styles.css:

```
:root {
  --color-Primary: #ff0505;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-family: Inter, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.hero {
  background-color: var(--color-Primary);
  height: 50rem;
}

h1 {
  padding-left: 2rem;
  padding-top: 2rem;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 9rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

In index.html, it works if I use `style="margin-top: 0px;"` in the h1 attribute. If I instead type it in styles.css as `margin-top: 0px;`, It doesn't work. Like why? Some one please help me

Comment: Is the path to your css file correct? Should be in the same folder as your html file. You can check in your browser's developer tools whether the file was loaded, but also from where your h1 tag gets its styles...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to change the order of 2 css files (**styles.css** and **normalize.css**)! The order matters! (Now the **h1** rule in normalize.css (`h1{font-size: 2em;margin: 0.67em 0;}`) override your rule from styles.css)

Answer (score 1):

You are injecting normalize.css after your own styles, that's why "margin:0px" is overriden by "margin: 0.67em 0;" rule from normalize.css.

All you need to do is to include normalize.css first.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```